# How can I change mediawiki's port?

Tags: mediawiki

I just installed mediawiki in a centos,but how can I change the port number instead of 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaWiki runs under httpd, so either change httpd's port, or listen on another port as well and create a virtual host on this new port for running MediaWiki.